# Why is this integer decrementing by itself?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, pointers, struct

Something tells me I'm doing something stupid. I haven't done any programming in a long time, and felt a bit rusty while writing this code. I'm sure I'll get back into the coding zen soon enough.

In the meantime, I'm have trouble with this code (specifically the `tab1->history_position` integer):

```
/* 
 * Created on February 17, 2011, 1:25 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct dir_instance
{
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    char *history[PATH_MAX/2];
    int history_size;
    int history_position;

};


struct dir_instance *dir_new_instance(char *path)
{
    struct dir_instance inst;
    inst.history_position=0;
    inst.history_size=0;

    inst.history[0]=malloc(strlen(path));
    strcpy(inst.history[0], path);

    return &inst;
}

void dir_add_history(struct dir_instance *inst, char *dir)
{
    inst->history[inst->history_position+1]=malloc(strlen(dir)+1);
    strcpy(inst->history[inst->history_position+1], dir);
}



void dir_goto(struct dir_instance *inst, char *dir)
{
    dir_add_history(inst, dir);
    inst->history_position++;
    inst->history_size++;
}

void dir_go_back(struct dir_instance *inst)
{
    if(inst->history_position>0)inst->history_position--;
}

void dir_go_forward(struct dir_instance *inst)
{
    if(inst->history[inst->history_position+1]!=NULL)inst->history_position++;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct dir_instance *tab1=dir_new_instance("/");
    dir_goto(tab1, "/home");

    printf("the current directory is: %s\n",tab1->history[tab1->history_position]);

    printf("the previous directory is: %s\n",tab1->history[tab1->history_position]);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm not sure what funny business is going on here, but like I said, I do suspect a stupid mistake. What seems to be happening, is that the integer `tab1->history_position` is decremented from 1 to 0 on line 65. No idea why. Please inform me.

Comment: Sorry, it's `printf("the current directory is: %s\n",tab1->history[tab1->history_position]);` from function `main`.

Comment: You are printing the same position in both `printf`s.

Comment: ruslik: See that's the problem, I get different values each time. (the value changes from 1 to 0)

Comment: @Hassan: it's because `tab1` **was** allocated on the stack. First call to `printf` modified that memory.

Comment: ruslik: Yeah that seems to be the problem. Still trying to work it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dir_instance that you're creating is allocated on the stack. That means it's invalid once `dir_new_instance` returns. Allocate it using `malloc` instead:

```
struct dir_instance *dir_new_instance(char *path)
{
    struct dir_instance* inst = (struct dir_instance*) malloc(sizeof(dir_instance));
    inst->history_position=0;
    inst->history_size=0;

    inst->history[0]=malloc(strlen(path + 1));
    strcpy(inst->history[0], path);

    return inst;
}
```

**EDIT**: Note the change to add 1 to the length of the string returned by `strlen`. You need that to allow for the terminating null character. (Many implementations have a `strdup` function which returns a malloc'd copy of the string, eliminating this error, but `strdup` is non-standard.)

Comment: You should probably be checking to see if `malloc` returns NULL.

Comment: @dan-breslau: For some reason this isn't compiling. Hold on, let me see if I can get it to work...

Comment: @Hassan: I didn't try to compile it. If you're still having problems, please paste the error message here.

Comment: @Hassan: Ah, I left out the cast on the new `malloc` call. I edited the answer to include it.

Comment: It's still giving an error:    main.c:23: error: ‘dir_instance’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:23: error: for each function it appears in.)

Comment: @Hassan: The declaration for `dir_instance` is a bit strange to my eyes, though I'm not certain that it's illegal. Try changing it to `typedef struct {...} dir_instance`, and then change occurances of `struct dir_instance` to `dir_instance`. (This is my preferred style; I try to avoid using `struct <name>`. I *think* your use of `typedef` in the declaration **should** be causing a syntax error from the get-go, since you don't actually name the type; you only name the struct, which is not the same thing.)

Comment: @dan-breslau WOW. Is all I have to say. Not only did that clean up some code, it fixed the problem altogether. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @Hassan: You're welcome. Umm, it would be nice if you'd accept the answer. We don't work entirely for free, you know... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

this here is wrong:

```
inst.history[0]=malloc(strlen(path));
strcpy(inst.history[0], path);
```

you should allocate `strlen(path)+1` to allow for the \0 to fit in.